# Ownership of members inside NSArray? without ARC

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, xcode5, nsarray, automatic-ref-counting

Is there a memory leak withOUT ARC?

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSNumber *numberForTest = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:123456];
[array addObject: numberForTest];
[numberForTest release];
NSLog(@"number = %@", numberForTest); //safe to access "numberForTest" after calling release???
[array release];
```

My concern is: Did

```
[array addObject: numberForTest];
```

make "numberForTest" not qualified to be deallocated, before

```
[array release];
```

???
After using Static Analyzer, no leak is reported. And the output is consistently correct. But I don't feel comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

[NSArray (and NSMutableArray) retain objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036268/does-nsarray-initwithobjects-retain-objects).

When you release your array, [all the objects in that array get released as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885839/with-an-nsarray-of-object-references-do-i-explicitly-release-all-objects-in-the).