# Will this simple NSMutableArray Example leak Memory using ARC?

Tags: ios, memory-management, nsmutablearray, automatic-ref-counting

I decided I need to go back over some basics recently, mostly to do with memory management and I'm beginning to doubt.

The reason I ask is because I'm a bit muddled with how to memory safe process items in array using temporary variables.

Could somebody wise in the ways of arc please tell me if this simple code will leak memory?

```
self.array=[NSMutableArray new];
// Retain +1
Test  *obj0 = [[Test alloc] init];
// Retain +1
[self.array addObject:obj0];
Test  *obj1 = nil;
//Retain +1
obj1=self.array[0];// does need to be __weak even though it has no owner?

[self.array removeAllObjects];

// is not null
NSLog(@"A: %@", obj1);
```

Comment: No, it won't leak memory.

Comment: Use Instruments to see if there are any leaks or retain cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add `obj0` to the array, its retain count will be incremented, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036268/does-nsarray-initwithobjects-retain-objects). It is then `+2`.
When you assign it to `obj1`, it still has an retain count of `+2`.
When you remove all objects from the array, their retain count will be decremented, so `obj0` has again anretain count of `+1`.
It thus won't leak.